# How to get from Google Analytics API if the option "bot filtering is checked" on a profile

Tags: google-analytics, filtering, google-analytics-api, bots

I have a list of different accounts with many properties and profiles on Google Analytics.
I would like to use the the Google Analytics API, to ask for each one of these profiles if the option "Bot Filtering" (Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders) is active or not. How could I do that? (I don't want to go through all accounts manually, it would be too much time consuming).
I have tried via the method GET of a profile or even in filter but I could not find this information.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that setting is not exposed in the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles) you could always submit a feature request to the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list).

Answer (score 2):

As per [changelog](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/changelog) of Management API, 17th December 2016, `botFilteringEnabled` property is added to the view [resource](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles).

Comment: December 2015; but yes, added after OP asked the question.